# How to use regular expressions to match digits inside parentheses?

Tags: python, python-re

I'm struggling with regular expressions.

Here is an example string:

```
(1-3)+XD(4-18):SP(19-36)+(37-96)
```

How would I extract the digits from the parentheses that are not preceded by SP or XD so that my result would be:

```
[1-3, 37-96]
```

Right now I am trying something like:

```
re.findall(r'[:|\+]\([0-9]+-[0-9]+\)', '(1-3)+XD(4-18):SP(19-36)+(37-96)')
```

But this returns:

```
['+(37-96)']
```

It misses the first (1-3) capture (because I cannot figure it out) and I also have to then operate on the substring returned from the match to extract the digits.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If the string is all like that, then the easier plan would be to use `re.split` to split on ':' and '+', and then examine each split token to see if it starts with SP or XD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind to exclude `SP` and `XD`, rather than explicitly matching `:` and `+`.

And if you don't want the results to include the parentheses, put a capture group around the numbers. Then `re.findall()` only returns the capture groups, not the matches.

```
re.findall(r'(?<!SP|XD)\((\d+-\d+)\)', '(1-3)+XD(4-18):SP(19-36)+(37-96)')
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eR30BD/2)